# In Selenium how to click on a hyper link that is embedded in table

Tags: selenium, html-table, webdriver

In selenium how to click on a hyper link that is embedded in table, here I want to click on link, this link is at a first entry in data table.

```html
<table class="table table-bordered">
<thead>
<tr></tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
     
<tr class="ng-scope" ng-repeat="item in view_data">
<td>
 <a class="ng-binding" title="Click to View Agent Profile" ng-href="#/agent/profile/46" href="#/agent/profile/46"></a>
</td>
<td class="ng-binding">
 1000008
</td>
<td class="ng-binding"></td>
<td class="ng-binding"></td>
<td class="ng-binding"></td>
<td class="ng-binding"></td>
<td class="ng-binding"></td>
 <td></td>
</tr>
      
<tr class="ng-scope" ng-repeat="item in view_data"></tr>
      
<tr class="ng-scope" ng-repeat="item in view_data"></tr>
      
<tr class="ng-scope" ng-repeat="item in view_data"></tr>
      
<tr class="ng-scope" ng-repeat="item in view_data"></tr>
       
</tbody>
</table>
```

**I tried below code but its not working..**

```
WebElement  tableLink = driver
.findElement(By
.xpath("//*table[@class='table table-bordered']/thead/tbody tr[@id='ng-scope']/td[@class='ng-binding']/a"));
tableLink.click();
```

Comment: Can you share which website? Or the DOM hierarchy of the page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I'd do it with just the snippet you posted

```
WebElement hyperlink = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("table.table a.ng-binding"));

hyperlink.click ();
```

Of course too many matches wouldn't work with this, but I'm sure you get the general idea behind the code.